# How to get all managed device's roleScopeTagIds using Intune Graph AP?

Tags: graph, managed, intune

The deviceManagement/manageddevices Intune Graph API results always return an empty array for the roleScopeTagIds property of all devices. Can anyone explain why or better yet, how to include those values?

If you supply the GUID for a device and call the same endpoint then the correct data is returned for the roleScopeTagIds property. Also, I get an "Invalid filter clause" error if I try to filter by the roleScopeTagIds property also.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your question. The behavior you are observing for the filtering and for device list API is by design.

Device list API:
In our initial implementation we did not want to query all scope tags for all the devices as we do not cap the number of scope tags that can be applied to a given device. The size of the data returned could potentially get large. So we decided to only return all scope tags when you select a single device.

Filtering:
As of now we do not support filtering on device scope tags to optimize overall latency for the device list. We do support other wide range of filters. Hope this helps.

We would like to learn more about your use case for fetching all applied scope tags at once.

Comment: Business case: automating role scope tag assignments to devices in Intune. Customer is large org that needs to delegate device mgnt to sub-entities in their org. 1st goal is to automate tagging all devices that have no tags so new/untagged devices don't appear for all Intune admins but only specific admins. 2nd goal is to automatically tag devices based on the sub-org responsible for the device. As is, I must query all devices followed by additional query for each and every device. Would be helpful if there was option to take performance hit up front to include tags of all devices.

Comment: What I have works but could be faster if tags are returned in first query so I could avoid an extra query for every device. If querying all devices continues to not include role scope tags then it would be better to eliminate rolescopetagids from the results altogether. Including it as empty array seems misleading. Do any other managed device properties behave this way? Another option would be to include a true/false property (which could allow filtering) indicating of a device has any tags but that may not be any faster on the backend. That would speed up scripts targeting untagged devices.

Comment: Any insight you could add to this related issue with Scope Tag behavior? Thanks. https://serverfault.com/q/1092617/6079

Answer (score 0):

As jcurl says it would be  realy nice to have roleScopeTags directly via graph and being able to filter on them.

To build a complete list of these for devices i ended up using [batched queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) to lower the amount of api calls needed (by 20).

I created a [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/37398955-imporve-searching-manageddevice-by-rolescopetagids) to get more possibilities on this

Answer (score 0):

the use case we have is generating PBI insights with filtering similiar like with Intune - which is based on the Scope Tags.
The general idea is to populate the scope's tags within all device polling through graph - which unfortunatle returns "empty" array
As you might be aware the Datawarehouse in majority of cases doesnt provide up to date information.